# JavaScript Show/Hide Page Elements Based on Radio Button

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a form and needing to only display certain inputs when radio is checked on Yes and it works...but when I click on No the elements stay present.

```
const sharing = document.querySelector('.sharing');
const twoBeds = document.querySelector('.two-beds');
const shareInput = document.querySelector('#occupant_share');
const hotelShow = document.querySelector('#occupant_hotel_0');
const hotelElement = document.querySelector('#occupant_hotel_1');
function init() {
  hotelShow.addEventListener('change', showHideShare);
  hotelElement.addEventListener('change', showHideShare);
  shareInput.addEventListener('change', showHideBeds);
}

let showHideShare = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  showHide(event.currentTarget, sharing);
};

let showHideBeds = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const target = event.currentTarget;
  showHide(target, twoBeds);
  const roommate = document.querySelector('.roommate');
  if (target.checked == true) {
    roommate.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    roommate.classList.add('hide');
    roommate.querySelector('#occupant_roommate').value = null;
  }
};

let showHide = (target, div) => {
  if (target.checked) {
    div.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    div.classList.add('hide');
    div.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(el) {
      el.checked = false;
    });
    const beds = div.querySelector('.two-beds');
    if (beds) beds.classList.add('hide');
    const roommate = div.querySelector('#occupant_roommate');
    if (roommate) roommate.value = null;
  }
};
```

The HTML looks like:

```
 <div class="row form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Do You Need A Hotel Room?</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-start form-check form-check-inline hotel-radio">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" name="occupant[hotel]" id="occupant_hotel_0">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="occupant_Yes">Yes</label>
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" name="occupant[hotel]" id="occupant_hotel_1">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="occupant_No">No</label>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="sharing">
   <div class="row form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Check In</label>
     <input class="form-control col-sm-4" type="date" name="occupant[check_in]" id="occupant_check_in">
   </div>
   <div class="row form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Check Out</label>
     <input class="form-control col-sm-4" type="date" name="occupant[check_out]" id="occupant_check_out">
   </div>
   <div class="row form-group room-info">
     <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Sharing Room</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-start form-check-inline sharing-radio">
       <input name="occupant[share]" type="hidden" value="0">
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="occupant[share]" id="occupant_share">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" name="occupant[share]" id="occupant_share_0">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="occupant_Yes">Yes</label>
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" name="occupant[share]" id="occupant_share_1">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="occupant_No">No</label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row form-group roommate hide">
     <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Roommate Name</label>
     <input class="form-control col-sm-4" type="text" name="occupant[roommate]" id="occupant_roommate">
   </div>
   <div class="row form-group two-beds hide">
     <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Request Two Beds</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-start form-check form-check-inline">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" name="occupant[two_beds]" id="occupant_two_beds_0">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="occupant_Yes">Yes</label>
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" name="occupant[two_beds]" id="occupant_two_beds_1">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="occupant_No">No</label>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The idea is that upon clicking on Yes (hotelShow) that it would then show all the elements that have the class assigned of sharing. I grabbed the No (hotelElement) just for the sake of grabbing it and seeing if there is something I need to do here.

If I use a checkbox, no worries, however I want to use radio buttons and trigger the event on that instead. Once I can get that to work I'd do the same on two beds (shareInput).

I thought it was an issue with the input[type="checkbox"] in my showHide but when I changed it to radio...didn't matter.

Is there a way for me to apply a hide here on the No?

EDIT:

I thought I could add in the following:

```
const hotelHide = document.querySelector('#occupant_hotel_1');
 function init() {
 same code
 hotelHide.addEventListener('change', hideNope);
}
let hotelNope = event => {
 event.preventDefault();
 hideShare(event.currentTarget, sharing);
}
let hideShare = (target, div) => {
 if (target.checked = true) {
  div.classList.add('hide');
 } else {
  div.classList.remove('hide');
  }
 }
```

The No option (hotelHide) is still not triggering the add of hide.

Comment: `const sharing = document.querySelector('.sharing');` gets the first element with the class "sharing", at the time it was run... I'm guessing that's not what you want. I'm guessing because you've not shown your HTML here, so we have to guess on the structure. It would be great if you could share a [mre], with the HTML, in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that proper advice could be given.

Comment: Also, radio buttons are typically grouped with several having the same name. At least one of the radio buttons with each name is checked at any one time. Setting all of them to be unchecked is odd.

Comment: Added in the HTML. Sharing contains all the inputs that I want included. It's a matter of hiding them upon clicking No.

Answer (score 1):

You want to update your radio button checked status like...

```
document.querySelector('#targetRadioButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#targetRadioButton').checked = !document.querySelector('#targetRadioButton').checked;
}
```

updated to reflect adding click event.

Comment: So I thought I would just need to update the let showHide where it has div.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]) to be ('[value="1"]) as that has a checked=false. That didn't work. Where were you thinking of adding that line?

Comment: Well this is just one way, but you could set it to the click event of the radio button itself. So when it's clicked it checks for toggles true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution was to add to my init function the const hide = document.querySelector('#falseradio'); Then change target.checked = true to target.value === '0'. Originally I was just setting it to = '0' not checking if it was present. Once I added in the additional = it worked.